# Modify data before render template in Django

Tags: python, django

What I need to do it's just replace some items from model before render. So just in each `business.address` replace '||' with ", ". I'm trying to do like that:

```
def category(request, q):
     businesses = Business.objects.filter(category_string__icontains=q)[:50]

     for b in businesses:
         if '||' in b.address:
             b.address.replace('||', ', ')
             print(b.address)
```

But I still see the same string without replacing. What's the reason?

Comment: @heemayl Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings are immutable in Python; hence, `str.replace` is not *in-place*.

You need to do the name binding (again):

```
b.address = b.address.replace('||', ', ')
```